# Создание кастомизируемого персонажа для браузерной текстовой RPG

Tags: javascript, node.js, scss, nextjs, nestjs

Для практики Nestjs и Nextjs решил создать текстовую браузерную игру по типу [Worldofclone](https://worldofclone.com), без особых наворотов и анимаций. Хочу реализовать кастомизацию персонажа методом расслоения изображения по типу как в игре [barbars](https://barbars.ru/). К примеру есть изображение персонажа только в белье, когда игрок находит новые вещи и экипирует их на персонажа, то на изображение наслаиваются нужные вещи по отдельности(руки, ноги, голова, тело, рюкзак). Не удалось найти как это можно реализовать, но уверен это возможно. Буду благодарен за любую инфу в этом вопросе

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Навскидку, первое что приходит в голову, использовать слои и соответственно z-index

Comment: z-index это само собой, я тоже других вариантов не вижу, но с помощью каких инструментов можно создать самого персонажа, и потом различные элементы одежды на отдельных частях тела, может графический редактор какой?